# grep command not working as my expectation

Tags: linux, shell, grep, sh, cut

I have a text file like mentioned below, and along with that I will pass an input for which I want a corresponding output.

Input file: `test.txt`

```
abc:abc_1
abcd:abcd_1
1_abcd:1_abcd_bkp
xyz:xyz_2
```

so if I use `abc` with the above test.txt file, I want `abc_1`; and if I pass `abcd`, I need `abcd_1` as output.

I tried `cat text.txt | grep abc | cut -d":" -f2,2`, but I am getting the output

```
abc_1
abcd_1
1_abcd_bkp
```

when I want only `abc_1`.

Comment: Do you mean to do this (with the underscore)? `cat text.txt | grep abc_ | cut -d":" -f2,2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po "^abc:\K.*" file
```

Output:

```
abc_1
```

---

> `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [regular expression](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html) with the `-e` switch.
In particular, regular expressions allow you to use caret (`^`) to express the start of a line.

Since you only care about `abc` when it's at the start of a line and it's followed by `:`, you want:

```
cat test.txt | grep -e "^abc:" | cut -d":" -f2,2
```

Output:

```
abc_1
```

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk -F: -v key="abc" '$1==key{print $2}'
```

using `:` as the delimiter do the look up for key on field 1 to return field 2.

Or, by moving the key in the script

```
awk -F: '$1=="abc"{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the exclude -v:

cat text.txt | grep abc | **grep -vi abc[a-z]**

not sure if that would work exactly, try something with that kind of idea

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying second field to be printed the whole line will be or in other cases lines.

```
awk -F: '/abc_/{print $2}' file
abc_1 

awk -F: 'NR==1,/abc/{print $2}' file
abc_1
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation and for example link to a documentation, please?

Comment: I have no link but taking into account the field separator as colon and abc matches first row print second field.

Comment: Add it to your answer, please. Description similar to @karakfa's answer would be nice. Thanks.